# Manually assigning parent ID with has_many/belongs_to association in custom class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a custom class to make AR instances from Feedjirra. I can't get the children instances to relate to their parent objects.

`Show has_many :episodes` - 
`Episode belongs_to :show` - 
`show_id` is always `nil`.

RSpec logs `@show.id` and `@episode.show_id` as equal to one another. However when I run `episode = Episode.first` after running an import in development, the episode has its `show_id` set to `nil`.

```
@show = Show.new

@show.name = @feed.title
@show.description = @feed.description
...

if @show.save
  puts "@show.id: #{@show.id}"
end

@episodes = []

@feed.entries.each do |item|
    @episodes.push(item)
end

@episodes.each do |item|
    @episode = @show.episodes.new

    @episode.name = item.title
    @episode.description = item.summary
    ...

    if @episode.save
      puts "@episode.show_id: #{@episode.show_id}"
    end
end
```

I tried using `@episode = @show.episodes.create`, as well as `@episode = Episode.new` with `@episode.show_id = @show.id`. They all log matching IDs but `show_id` is still `nil` on the instances. Every other column is filled in correctly.

---

I thought the issue may have had to do with using `add_foreign_key`:

```
class AddShowToEpisodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :episodes, :show, index: true
    add_foreign_key :episodes, :shows, column: :show_id
  end
end
```

So I removed that and used the standard `foreign_key: true` but it had no effect.

```
class RemoveShowFromEpisodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :episodes, :show_id
  end
end

class AddShowBackToEpisodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :episodes, :show, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Here's the full code in case it helps.

importers_controller.rb:

```
class Admin::ImportersController < Admin::ApplicationController
  before_action :set_importer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @importers = policy_scope(Importer)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @importer = Importer.new
    authorize @importer
  end

  def create
    @importer = Importer.new(importer_params)
    authorize @importer

    if @importer.save
      require "subscription_importer"
      SubscriptionImporter.new(@importer)

      flash[:notice] = "Importer added."
      redirect_to admin_importers_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Importer not added."
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def set_importer
    @importer = Importer.find(params[:id])
    authorize @importer
  end

  def importer_params
    params.require(:importer).permit(:name, :url, :source)
  end
end
```

subscription_importer.rb:

```
class SubscriptionImporter
  def initialize(importer)
    @importer = importer
    @feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse @importer.url

    if @importer.source === "iTunes"
      itunes_parser(@importer)
    end
  end

  def itunes_parser(importer)
    @importer = importer

    # Parser
    @feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse @importer.url

    # Show
    @show = Show.new

    @show.name = @feed.title
    @show.description = @feed.description
    @show.logo = @feed.itunes_image
    @show.explicit = explicit_check(@feed.itunes_explicit)
    @show.genre = @feed.itunes_categories
    @show.tags = @feed.itunes_keywords
    @show.url = @feed.url
    @show.language = @feed.language

    if @show.save
      puts "Show import succeeded"
      puts "@show.id: #{@show.id}"
    else
      puts "Show import failed"
    end

    # Episodes
    @episodes = []

    @feed.entries.each do |item|
        @episodes.push(item)
    end

    @episodes.each do |item|
        @episode = @show.episodes.new

        @episode.name = item.title
        @episode.description = item.summary
        @episode.release = item.published
        @episode.image = item.itunes_image
        @episode.explicit = explicit_check(item.itunes_explicit)
        @episode.tags = item.itunes_keywords
        @episode.url = item.enclosure_url
        @episode.duration = item.itunes_duration

        if @episode.save
          puts "Episode import succeeded"
          puts "@episode.show_id: #{@episode.show_id}"
        else
          puts "Episode import failed"
        end
    end
  end

  def explicit_check(string)
    if string == "yes" || "Yes"
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

create_importer_spec.rb:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Admins can create importers" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :admin) }

  context "admins" do
    before do
      login_as(user)
      visit "/"
      click_link "Admin"
      click_link "Importers"
      click_link "New Importer"
    end

    scenario "with valid credentials" do
      fill_in "Name", with: "The Stack Exchange Podcast"
      fill_in "Url", with: "https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/podcast/" # Needs stubbing
      select "iTunes", from: "Source"
      click_button "Create Importer"

      expect(page).to have_content "Importer added"
      expect(page).to have_content "The Stack Exchange Podcast"
    end

    scenario "with invalid credentials" do
      fill_in "Name", with: ""
      fill_in "Url", with: ""
      click_button "Create Importer"

      expect(page).to have_content "Importer not added"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please verify if show_id is really a integer field in database?

Comment: @TriveniBadgujar It is yes, just checked in pgAdmin. I also re-added the column (see edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `episodes` functionality in your `SubscriptionImporter` class is causing the problem...

```
@episodes = []

@feed.entries.each do |item|
  @episodes.push(item) #-> each "@episodes" is a FeedJirra object
end

@episodes.each do |episode|
   #-> you're now creating an episode in the same call as show, which will either mean that show is not persisted or perhaps some other error 
end
```

---

I would personally limit the `SubscriptionImporter` functionality to *only* return data. You should be parsing that data through the respective models:

```
#app/controllers/admin/importers_controller.rb
class Admin::ImportersController < Admin::ApplicationController
   def create
      @import = Importer.new import_params 
      if @import.save
         @import.parse_show if @import.itunes?
      end
   end

   private

   def import_params
      params.require(:importer).permit(:name, :url, :source)
   end
end

#app/models/importer.rb
class Importer < ActiveRecord::Base
   def feed
      return false unless itunes?
      origin = Feedjirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(self.url)
      return {
         name:        origin.title,
         description: origin.description,
         logo:        origin.itunes_image,
         explicit:    explicit_check(origin.itunes_explicit),
         genre:       origin.itunes_categories,
         tags:        origin.itunes_keywords,
         url:         origin.url,
         language:    origin.language,
         entries:     origin.entries
      }
   end

   def parse_show
      Show.create(feed)
   end

   def itunes?
      self.source == "iTunes" #-> true/false 
   end

   private

   def explicit_check
      string == "yes" || "Yes" #-> true/false
   end
end

#app/models/show.rb
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :episodes

   attr_accessor :entries
   after_create :create_episodes #-> might not persist entries

   def create_episodes
      if self.entries.any?
          self.entries.each do |item|
             self.episodes.create({
                name: item.title
                description: item.summary,
                release:     item.published,
                image:       item.itunes_image,
                explicit:    explicit_check?(item.itunes_explicit),
                tags:        item.itunes_keywords,
                url:         item.enclosure_url,
                duration:    item.itunes_duration
             })
          end
      end
   end

   private

   def explicit_check?
      string == "yes" || "Yes"
   end
end
```

The above will allow you to create an `@importer`, pull the `feed` from it, and populate `Show` & `Episode` models with the returned data.

Whilst this *should* resolve your issue, you need to consider [`OOP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) -- making each element an object.

---

**Update**

If you wanted to objectify this even more, there is a simple pattern to adopt:

1. `Importer` is all you need to save -- everything else should happen around this
2. `Show` + `Episode` *could* be the same class / table for all I know

With this in mind, you could do the following:

```
#app/controllers/admin/importers_controller.rb
class Admin::ImportersController < Admin::ApplicationController
   def create
      @import = Importer.new import_params 
      @import.save
   end

   private

   def import_params
      params.require(:importer).permit(:name, :url, :source)
   end
end

#app/services/feed.rb
class Feed
    attr_reader :params, :show, :episode, :origin
    def initialize(params)
      @params = params
    end

    def origin
       @origin = Feedjirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse params[:source]
    end

    def show
       @show = ShowHelper.new @origin
    end

    def episodes
      @show.episodes
    end
end

#app/services/show_helper.rb
class ShowHelper 
    attr_reader :origin
    def initialize(origin)
      @origin = origin
    end

    def name
      @origin.title
    end

    def description
      @origin.summary || @origin.description
    end

    def logo
      @origin.itunes_image
    end

    def explicit
      %r{^yes$} =~ @origin.itunes_explicit
    end

    def genre
      @origin.itunes_categories
    end

    def tags
      @origin.itunes_keywords
    end

    def url
      @origin.url
    end

    def language
      @origin.language
    end

    def episodes
      @origin.entries
    end
end

#app/models/importer.rb
class Importer < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_create :parse_show, if: "itunes?"
   validates :source, :url, :name, presence: true

   def itunes?
      source == "iTunes" 
   end

   def feed
      @feed = Feed.new(self)
   end

   private

   def parse_show
      @show = Show.new(feed.show) if feed && feed.show
      if @show.save && @show.entries.any?
         @show.entries.each do |entry|
            @show.episodes.create ShowHelper.new(entry)
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: I like this much more. How should I handle different sources? A `case` statement in `feed`?

Comment: You'd be best extracting the "parse" functionality into another class (much like `SubscriptionImporter`) and introducing some logic into `Importer` to pull the required data.

Comment: Something I'd like to look at would be [`Service Objects`](https://www.netguru.co/blog/service-objects-in-rails-will-help). I could try writing one for this if you feel it appropriate.

Comment: Interesting, that does seem fitting here. I'd be interested to see what you think one should look like in my case.

Comment: Certainly, let me just finish something else. [`@max`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) is the man for service objects

Comment: Done, it's long; can chat about it if required

Comment: Awesome. I'll implement it and let you know if I have questions. Thank you Rich.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102752/discussion-between-jorrin-and-rich-peck).

Comment: Here if you want to chat

Comment: I clicked "automatically move this discussion to chat" and it generated that comment/link. I sent you a message, did you receive it?

Comment: Back, send another comment and we can talk

Comment: I'm not sure how to generate another room. Does [this link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102752/discussion-between-jorrin-and-rich-peck) work for you?

Comment: Okay great, I sent you a message